# Process Builder Order of Operations

Tags: process-builder

I have a question on the order of elements being fired within a Process Buidler. Please see attached photo.

Scenario: Both elements #1 & #2 are applicable and meet the criteria of the changes made on the record.

Questions:

1. Do elements #1 & #2 fire consecutively?
2. Does element #2 wait for the actions of #1 to complete before continuing?
3. Some other scenario of actions happen?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action blocks for #1 and #2 will execute sequentially

- If 50 recs meet decision block 1's condition and the same 50 recs meet decision block 2's condition, the Create Stips Flow will be invoked 50+50 times (i.e. 100 Flow Interviews, bulkified at 50 recs, twice).
- If 50 recs meet decision block 1's condition and a different set of 10 recs meet decision block 2's condition, the Create Stips Flow will be invoked 50+10 times (i.e. 60 Flow Interviews, bulkified once for 50 and bulkified again for 10).

Comment: Thanks for the response, lets say the the actions were different - for example #1 & #3 were applicable. Would the create stips flow fire and complete (#1) THEN the email alert would be sent (#3). I want to confirm these would handle sequentially and not concurrently.

Comment: Process Builder actions will not execute concurrently; all of the actions execute in the context of a single transaction.  As an aside, you should consider using Flow rather than PB as that is SFDC direction

Comment: not to mention you want to be careful if you're hoping an update from #1 will trigger criteria #3 in the same process builder. There's a [critical update](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_cruc_criteria.htm&type=5&release=220) that will make it so all PB criteria evaluates the record as it was when it entered the PB.